# C++ code to test for positive/negative using switch and "?:"

Tags: c++

I am tasked with writing a code to test whether a number is positive, negative, or zero using switch and "?:". Here's what I have. Negative values don't seem to work and I can't figure out how to implement zero. In fact, I don't really quite understand how the whole case1, case2 and switch syntax and how it works in general.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a;
int b;

cout << "Please enter the value to be tested: ";
cin >> a;

(a > 0) ? (b = 1) : (b = 2);

switch (b)
{
    case 1:
        cout << "The given value is positive." << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "The given value is negative." << endl;
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use *descriptive names*. E.g. instead of `b`, think about `is_positive`. Then you see more easily that it should be of type `bool`. Presumably your `b` is of type `int`, but you don't show. Depending on its type even the first assignments may be bugs. The testing of different values than you assign is definitely buggy. Anyway you should post a **complete but minimal example**.

Comment: The switch statement: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: Think of `case 1:` as `if(b == 1)`, and `case 2:` as `else if(b == 2)`

Comment: make sure you are using an `int`, not an `unsigned int` as `unsigned` can only be positive.

Comment: 1. how are `a` and `b` defined? 2. what does `a > -1` test? (hint: nothing useful ... negatives are `< 0` and positives are `> 0` ... your test will return the same for `-0.5`, `0`, and `0.5`) 3. it appears you wish to set `b` to `-1` if `a` is negative, `1` if a is positive, and `0` o/w ... where is the code that sets `b = 0`? 4. you set `b` to a value of `-1` or `1`, but your `switch` statement checks only `1` and `2` ... what is going to happen if `b` is `-1`? `0`? does the `case 2` code path ever execute?

Comment: ok i have changed it

Comment: i changed the code, but i still cant find out how to test for zero

Comment: `bool b = (a >= 0) ? true : false`

Comment: `(a > 0) ? (b = 1) : (b = 2);` would `b = (a > 0) ? 1: 2;`  be more readable and less prone to errors in the future using that pattern

Comment: You need a second test for zero. Your first test (as writ) says is a greater than zero? If it IS zero, then it fails the test and b=2. Once you know b is 2 (i.e. inside your case) you can run another test and see if a is less than 0. If it's not, it is zero.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `?` twice? If so you could go `b = (a > 0) ? 1 : ((a == 0) ? 0 : -1);`  which would result in `b` having the same sign as `a` and then you can test `b` with 3 cases in the `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

**Switch Statement:**

> The switch statement provides a convenient alternative to the `if` when
>   dealing with a multi-way branch. Suppose we have some integer value
>   called test and want to do different operations depending on whether
>   it has the value 1, 5 or any other value, then the switch statement
>   could be employed

**Syntax:**

```
switch(expression resulting to integer literals/integer literals/enumeration types/){
    case constant-expression  :
       statement(s);
       break; //optional
    case constant-expression  :
       statement(s);
       break; //optional
    // you can have any number of case statements.

    default : //Optional and one default statement can be present for a switch
       statement(s);
}
```

**The following rules apply to a switch statement:**

- The expression used in a switch statement must have an integral or
  enumerated type, or be of a class type in which the class has a
  single conversion function to an integral or enumerated type.
- You can have any number of case statements within a switch. Each case
  is followed by the value to be compared to and a colon.
- The constant-expression for a case must be the same data type as the 
  variable in the switch, and it must be a constant or a literal.
- When the variable being switched on is equal to a case, the
  statements following that case will execute until a break statement
  is reached.
- When a break statement is reached, the switch terminates, and the
  flow of control jumps to the next line following the switch
  statement.
- Not every case needs to contain a break. If no break appears, the
  flow of control will fall through to subsequent cases until a break
  is reached.
- A switch statement can have an optional default case, which must
  appear at the end of the switch. The default case can be used for
  performing a task when none of the cases is true. No break is needed 
  in the default case.

**It works as follows:-**

- The expression, just test in this case, is evaluated.
- The case labels are checked in turn for the one that matches the
  value.
- If none matches, and the optional default label exists, it is
  selected, otherwise control passes from the switch compound statement
- If a matching label is found, execution proceeds from there. Control
  then passes down through all remaining labels within the switch
  statement. As this is normally not what is wanted, the `break`
  statement is normally added before the next case label to transfer
  control out of the switch statement.
- One useful exception occurs when    you want to do the same
  processing for two or more values. Suppose    you want values 1 and
  10 to do the same thing, then:-

  case 1 :
  /*.
  any number of cases
    . 
  */
  case 10:
    // Process below statements for case 1 to 10
    break;

works because the test = 1 case just **"drops through"** to the next section.

**Conditional Operator:**

The ternary operator (?:) is a very useful conditional expression used in C and C++. It's effects are similar to the if statement but with some major advantages.

The basic syntax of using the ternary operator is thus:

```
(condition) ? (if_true) : (if_false)
```

Which is basically the same as:

```
if (condition)
    if_true;
else
    if_false;
```

Therefore if "condition" is true, the second expression is executed ("if_true"), if not, the third is executed ("if_false").

For you Code:

You can use any of the way to find, one way is,

```
#define POSITIVE (1)
#define NEGATIVE (-(1))
#define ZERO (0)
switch ( ( user_input >= ZERO )? POSITIVE : NEGATIVE )
{
    case POSITIVE:
        if( user_input == ZERO )
        {
          cout << "The given value is a Zero." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
          cout << "The given value is positive." << endl;
        }
        break;
    case NEGATIVE:
        cout << "The given value is negative." << endl;
        break;
}
```